# Breakpoints in Dartium not working

Tags: intellij-idea, dart, angular-dart, dart-editor, dartium

So if I add break points in .dart files that are located in /web directory of my project, it works fine. For example I'm using AngularDart and the main.dart file works. However when I try to put a breakpoint in anything in the /lib directory, Dartium doesn't stop on them.

How can I get the breakpoints in Dartium to work with the /lib directory?

Note that I've tried putting breakpoints with Dart Editor, IntelliJ with Dart Plugin and also directly in Dartium and nothing works. Is this intended?

Comment: It is absolutely not intended. We can set break point even `dart:io` library as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To set breakpoints in dependencies search the source inside the `(no domain)` node and set the breakpoint there. Breakpoints don't hit when set somewhere in the `packages` node.

[image]

You can also use the `breakpoint` statement for the debugger top pop up. See [Does Dart have a 'breakpoint' statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612530/does-dart-have-a-breakpoint-statement) for more details.

Comment: Yes you're right. In Dartium you can see this when you go in the source tab: http://i.imgur.com/ZSWmyDe.png so the files can be found under packages and under (no domain) for me at least. If I put a break point in a file opened from (no domain) it works. Thanks Günter you're the man!

Comment: Thanks for confirming, I couldn't remember these details.

Answer (score 2):

I will combine the accepted answer + comment to that answer. Breakpoints 100% works only when you set them for files inside `(no domain)` category on `Sources` tab.

As I understand, in category with your domain name they are working only for files that was included with `<script>` tag. They won't work for imported files.

I have created an issue: [Dartium ignores breakpoints set not in (no domain) category](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=21601).

Comment: Did you try putting your .dart files directly in the /web directory? Seems to make it work for me (not in the (no domain) category)

Comment: @Pacane I won't break my app's structure for debugging purposes. And what if you need to debug packages? This solution won't help.

Answer (score 0):

If you set break pointors from Dart Editor, then you should run your application from Dart Editor.

If you're using Dartium only, then you should set break pointors from `Chrome Developer Tool`. (Accepted answer)

Comment: Yeah that's what I did though. I tried putting the breakpoints from the IDE AND launching dartium from there, but also launching pub serve manually AND adding breakpoints directly in dartium.