# Does Dart have a 'breakpoint' statement?

Tags: debugging, dart

Is there a statement in Dart to make the debugger halt without setting a breakpoint while debugging?

There are situations where it would be helpful be able to hardcode a breakpoint. I run into this for example to simplify remote debugging, to ensure the execution stops early and then I can add further breakpoints using the debugger.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This was just introduced
(Dart VM version: 1.11.0-edge.131775 (Tue Jun  2 14:25:22 2015) on "linux_x64")

```
import 'dart:developer'; 

void main() {
  debugger(); 
  // or
  debugger(msg: 'because I say so');
}
```

there is also a conditional variant

```
// Debugger.breakHereIf(bool expr); // current
debugger(when: somethingIsTrue, msg: 'investigate'); // later
```

See also [Breakpoints in Dartium not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822902/breakpoints-in-dartium-not-working) for how to use Dartiums debugger.

Comment: yeah but you can't interact with the variables. the program just stops.

Comment: Should behave the same as a breakpoint in the IDE, otherwise I'd consider this a bug.