# cant hit a breakpoint in dartium when trying to break a load function on a Datagrid

Tags: intellij-idea, dart, dart-polymer

I have a defined Datagrid object, which will have an attr:value of:

```
retrievePagedDataFunc="{{retrieveDataFunction}}"
```

in HTML, which associates with the dart file behind it.

```
Future<Page<User>> retrieveDataFunction(PageRequest pr){
  UserQuery uq = new UserQuery();  //BreakPoint Here

  return _service.getUsersPagedQuery(uq,pr);
}
```

with a break point in IntelliJ hoping that will cause it to stop at the break point.

I was looking at the Dartium source tab of the dev tools trying to find the correct file again, and maybe add a breakpoint within Dartium as well.  There seems to be an issue with the files being changed around so i cant seem to find the files i was really working with.

I noticed that i could put a breakpoint in main.dart but that doesnt seem to help me when i want to break on a particular templated component utility call.

Comment: I run into such an issue as well occasionally. I think this needs a full repo case to pin it down. Setting in breakpoints in Dartium usually works. It's possible that the exact code line doesn't exist because of transformers modifying it. This is often the cause for breakpoints not hitting. Another cause might be "weird" imports that don't comply with pub guidelines about how dart files should be organized and imported.

Comment: I cant show it really since it is a private company repo.  I just wasnt sure if things are organized by dart and if defined src files are organized in relation namespaces, etc.  It seems that packages will load pretty much everything which is imported.  Ahh, ok.  Thanks for the edit to your code.

Comment: It would be helpful to strip it down to the minimum code that still allows to reproduce anyway I guess. Actually `pub` != Dart. Dart processes anything you throw (import) at it, even from URLs, but that's no beaten path. Tools usually expect pub conventions to be met.

Comment: ill see if i can get a simple sample of this running. If not, i will just have to delete this thread.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822902/breakpoints-in-dartium-not-working it might help you.

Comment: Imports that don't comply with the pub package layout conventions are also known to cause such problems.