# How to correctly run Angular2 dart application in Dartium browser from IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, dart, dartium

How to correctly open Dart application in Dartium?

I am doing [this](https://angular.io/docs/dart/latest/tutorial/toh-pt3.html) Angular2-Dart tutorial.

To get working application, I can run `pub build` command, then start http server on `build/web` directory and applciation will work correctly.

Also, I can run `pub serve` command, then open `localhost:8080` address in browser, wait some time for Dart compilation and the application will work too.

How to correctly run application in Dartium? I am going to `web/index.html` file in IDEA, press Alt + F2 (to open variants to open application with) and press dartium. I don't see working application now. I see only `Loading...` message (because my html is `<my-app>Loading...</my-app>`).

I see this window [image]

Also, what are benefits of using Dartium web browser when developing Dart application? For example, `pub serve` recompile Dart code on each page refresh. It takes really much time. May be I wouldn't spend so much time for compilation with Dartium?

One way, I can correctly open my Dart application is dartium is:

1. Set up http server on `web` directory (index.html file is here).
2. Run this server (for example on 8086 port0
3. Open `localhost:8086` in dartium.

After some time application is correctly opened. May be there is some problems with my intellij idea?

Update:

I got this in `pub serve` tab in IDEA when I am trying to open `index.html` with Dartium:

```
C:\tools\dart-sdk\bin\pub.bat serve web --port=53852
Loading source assets...
Loading angular2 and dart_to_js_script_rewriter transformers...
Serving ng2_hero_app web on http://localhost:53852
[web] GET index.html => (cached) ng2_hero_app|web/index.html
[web] GET Served 9 cached assets.
Build completed successfully
[web] GET Served 2 cached assets.
[web] GET Served 3 cached assets.
[web] GET packages/angular2/src/core/metadata.dart => (cached) angular2|lib/src/core/metadata.dart
[web] GET packages/angular2/src/core/util.dart => (cached) angular2|lib/src/core/util.dart
[web] GET packages/angular2/src/core/di.dart => (cached) angular2|lib/src/core/di.dart
[web] GET packages/angular2/src/facade/facade.dart => (cached) angular2|lib/src/facade/facade.dart
[web] GET packages/angular2/src/core/application_ref.dart => (cached) angular2|lib/src/core/application_ref.dart
[web] GET packages/angular2/src/core/application_tokens.dart => (cached) angular2|lib/src/core/application_tokens.dart
[web] GET packages/angular2/src/core/zone.dart => (cached) angular2|lib/src/core/zone.dart
[web] GET packages/angular2/src/core/render.dart => (cached) angular2|lib/src/core/render.dart
[web] GET packages/angular2/src/core/linker.dart => (cached) angular2|lib/src/core/linker.dart
[web] GET packages/angular2/src/core/debug/debug_node.dart => (cached) angular2|lib/src/core/debug/debug_node.dart
[web] GET packages/angular2/src/core/testability/testability.dart => (cached) angular2|lib/src/core/testability/testability.dart
[web] GET packages/angular2/src/core/change_detection.dart => (cached) angular2|lib/src/core/change_detection.dart
[web] GET packages/angular2/src/core/platform_directives_and_pipes.dart => (cached) angular2|lib/src/core/platform_directives_and_pipes.dart
[web] GET packages/angular2/src/core/platform_common_providers.dart => (cached) angular2|lib/src/core/platform_common_providers.dart
[web] GET packages/angular2/src/core/application_common_providers.dart => (cached) angular2|lib/src/core/application_common_providers.dart
[web] GET packages/angular2/src/core/reflection/reflector.dart => (cached) angular2|lib/src/core/reflection/reflector.dart
[web] GET packages/angular2/src/core/reflection/types.dart => (cached) angular2|lib/src/core/reflection/types.dart
[web] GET packages/angular2/src/core/reflection/platform_reflection_capabilities.dart => (cached) angular2|lib/src/core/reflection/platform_reflection_capabilities.dart
[web] GET packages/angular2/src/facade/lang.ngfactory.dart => (cached) angular2|lib/src/facade/lang.ngfactory.dart
[web] GET packages/angular2/src/platform/browser_common.ngfactory.dart => (cached) angular2|lib/src/platform/browser_common.ngfactory.dart
[web] GET packages/angular2/core.ngfactory.dart => (cached) angular2|lib/core.ngfactory.dart
[web] GET packages/angular2/src/core/angular_entrypoint.ngfactory.dart => (cached) angular2|lib/src/core/angular_entrypoint.ngfactory.dart
[web] GET packages/angular2/src/facade/collection.dart => (cached) angular2|lib/src/facade/collection.dart
[web] GET packages/angular2/src/core/change_detection/change_detection.dart => (cached) angular2|lib/src/core/change_detection/change_detection.dart
[web] GET packages/angular2/src/core/metadata/di.dart => (cached) angular2|lib/src/core/metadata/di.dart
[web] GET Served 2 cached assets.
```

And I see this in Dartium: 
[image]

I got this text when I try to open index.html with Chrome:

```
    C:\tools\dart-sdk\bin\pub.bat serve web --port=54019
Loading source assets...
Loading angular2 and dart_to_js_script_rewriter transformers...
Serving ng2_hero_app web on http://localhost:54019
[web] GET index.html => (cached) ng2_hero_app|web/index.html
[web] GET Served 3 cached assets.
Build completed successfully
```

And this is pic:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Run and debug in Dartium**

In IDEA (or WebStorm) you can just right-click on `web/index.html` and select **`Run (index.html)`** or **`Debug (index.html)`** and IDEA should

- start `pub serve`
- start Dartium
- load index.html

I don't know what `Alt + F2` does because there are various of keyboard shortcut settings.

**Run in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, ...**

You should also be able to just copy the URL from Dartium to Chrome or other browsers and `pub serve` serves the Dart-to-JavaScript transpiled application. This is more efficient than `pub build` because it doesn't need to rebuild the entire application after a modification of the source. It can reuse cached parts where code didn't change and is therefore much faster.

**Known issue**

There was an IDEA (and WebStorm) issue recently  that resulted in a behavior similar to the one you describe. Please check you have the latest IDEA version.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for you answer. You help me so much in Dart world :) I updated my question. I can open my app with Dartium only using one way.  Also, I am updating IDEA right now :)

Comment: I updated IDEA. I tried again open index.html in Dartium and in Chrome. I provdided `pub serve` logs and screens.

Comment: Actually, I don't think I have problem with Dartium... I have problems with running and debuggin application from intellij. I tried to bind `./web` directory to my http server and tried to open it in Dart. Worked like a charm. But. I have problems to open my application from IDEA. It is another question, I think... Thank you.

Comment: I am trying this: "In IDEA (or WebStorm) you can just right-click on web/index.html and select Run (index.html) or Debug (index.html) and IDEA should". And I got this: https://i.gyazo.com/927b0506b0450cd9dddc539e5a8233cf.png

Comment: Actually, openning app from IDEA still not works. I can open app in Dartium browser, if I create http server on `<root>/web` directory. App works correctly. But if I open (right mouse button click and `Open in...`) app is not working. `pub serve` or `pub build` and opening localhost:8080 (or 8086 for `pub build`) works correctly in any browser. So I still can't open app from idea.

Comment: I just check another my question with your answer. There is screenshot with opened Chrome DevTools in answer in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822902/breakpoints-in-dartium-not-working) post. There is port 63342. Look like app was opened from IDEA :(

Comment: There should be a `Run (index.html)` and `Debug (index.html)` (in addition to `Open in` which is not what I suggest in my answer!!). If they are not shown then you probably haven't enabled Dart support in WebStorm. Normally WebStorm recognizes a Dart project (I guess when `pubspec.yaml` is found) and suggests to enable Dart support.

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3 and there is still no Run/Debug when right-clicking on web/index.html. My project is recognized as a Dart project (Pub actions are displayed when looking at pubspec.yaml).

Comment: `web/inder.html` always for me. Only tests don't provide a debug menu and require a manual run config. No idea what could cause your oroblem

Answer (score 1):

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3 and there is still no Run/Debug when right-clicking on web/index.html. My project is recognized as a Dart project (Pub actions are displayed when looking at pubspec.yaml).

When i Open in Browser|Dartium two things happen:

1) Problem description

Dartium opens with the url http://localhost:63342/enighet_register/web/index.html?_ijt=kg22cgo907ps6ivcv3sm5dmvt1 which displays forever loading because as the console log shows as Dartium is unable to find the other resources from the web directory (e.g. requested via http://localhost:63342/main.dart ). If you compare these two urls you notice that the first one retains the project name and web-directory, while the second one is relative to index.html. This seems to be the source of the problem. (main.dart is available via http://localhost:63342/enighet_register/web/main.dart)

2) Workaround

Opening the file in Dartium also starts the Pub Serve-tab in IntelliJ (next to the Dart Analysis- and Terminal-tab). Here we get the line:
"Serving enighet_register web on http://localhost:39030"
opening this url in Dartium (or other browsers) works perfektly fine (the port is dynamic, so check the output each time).

Not sure if you can debug in IntelliJ though, but you can set breakpoints and debug within Dartium!