# Problems with debugging Dart code in Dartium?

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart, dartium

I am writing small dart application. Actually, I am doing Angular2 tutorial. I have same code as in [this github repository](https://github.com/angular-examples/quickstart).

I open `web/index.html` in Dartium and application work.

I open console, source tab. I found `main.dart` file, put breakpoint in it and reload page. Chrome stops on this breakpoint. It is okay.

But, when I find `app_component.dart` file and set up breakpoint in it, Chrome doesn't stop on it. Why?

Look [this line(github repo link)](https://github.com/sharikovvladislav/angular2-hero-app/blob/a4ba11adbb75cd0d33fd184d250b9517cf20866d/lib/app_component.dart#L94). I put info message when onSelect handler is called. I also put breakpoint here in Dartium. I got message in console, but Dartium debugger doesn't stop on it. Why?

Comment: If http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822902/breakpoints-in-dartium-not-working doesn't solve your problem, add a comment to get the question reopened.

Comment: Yes. It solved problem. Thank you.